# How to open a new terminal from my working folder in Solaris 10?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal, working-directory

In Solaris 8, I could to `ctrl+t` to open a terminal from the file manager. But in Solaris 10, I can't seem to be able to.

I try to create a shortcut key by `gnome-terminal`, but the pwd is always my home directory. I want a way to set up a keyboard shortcuts to be able to use in file browser to open up a terminal that has pwd of the directory I am currently on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Gnome desktop environment and not the legacy CDE one, I'm afraid this functionality which I believe required the plugin nautilus-open-terminal was not available. If you find its source code for the nautilus release Solaris 10 uses, you might try to build it from source. Otherwise, transitioning to Solaris 11 would be a smart move as Solaris 10 is 11 years old now.